# Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const onSignupPress = () => {
    console.log(userName, email, password);
    firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc("id0002").set({
      user_name: userName,
      user_email: email,
      user_password: password,
    });
  };
```

Where Iam doing wrong?

I wanted to connect with my firebase but failing

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimum debug information: 1) the output of `console.log(userName, email, password);`, 2) the exact, complete error message you get.

Comment: Don't share the credentials, but are they set?  From the error message, it sounds like they are not set correctly. How are you setting them? Is there a picticular guide you are following? Most likely the problem exists outside of the code you have shared.